# How to find if a ViewController is pulled or pushed?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I have a UIView animation in `viewWillAppear:` method, behavior of the animation is related to `ControlView`'s movement. If NavigationController is pushing the `View` the animation should play in normal, if `View` is pulled back the animation should play in reverse. 
How can I find out if the current `ViewController` is being pushed or pulled in `viewWillAppear:` method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In iOS7 you can implement UINavigationController delegate method

```
- (id <UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning>)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController animationControllerForOperation:(UINavigationControllerOperation)operation fromViewController:(UIViewController *)fromVC toViewController:(UIViewController *)toVC;
```

and get info from *UINavigationControllerOperation* operation

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, UINavigationControllerOperation) {
    UINavigationControllerOperationNone,
    UINavigationControllerOperationPush,
    UINavigationControllerOperationPop,
};
```

Documentation says:

> Called to allow the delegate to return an interactive animator object
>   for use during view controller transitions.
>
> Implement this delegate method when you want to provide a custom,
>   interactive transition between view controllers as they are added to
>   or removed from the navigation stack. The object you return should
>   configure the interactivity aspects of the transition and should work
>   with the object in the animationController parameter to start the
>   animations.
>
> The animator object responsible for managing the transition
>   animations, or nil if you want to use the standard navigation
>   controller transitions.

Thus, in the case of simple observing of transition you should return nil in this method.

Comment: Thanks, could you give me more explanation how to use it? I added `UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning` delegate to my `viewController` .h file. but this method is not getting called. And I don't know what should be returned? `self`?

Comment: @Hadu you need set you view controller to be the delegate for its navigation controller. In loadView method you need to add self.navigationController.delegate=self. Then the method described in my answer will be called each time at pop and push.

Comment: Could you please tell me what should be returned in the method?

Comment: @Hadu please see explanation in the text extended.

Comment: Note that implementing this delegate method disables the navigation controller's interactive pop gesture recognizer.  See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38859457/5352503) for how to re-enable it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `UINavigationController`'s `viewControllers` property:

`@property(nonatomic, copy) NSArray *viewControllers`

According to [Apple Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html): `The root view controller is at index 0 in the array, the back view controller is at index n-2, and the top controller is at index n-1, where n is the number of items in the array.`

You can print the index of viewControllers Array and it will let you know that on which viewController you are standing now.

```
NSArray * viewControllers = [[self navigationController] viewControllers];
NSLog(@"%@",viewControllers.description);
```

Comment: I don't want to know which viewController I'm standing on, I want to know from which viewController I'm coming from.

Comment: simple when you print the viewControllers array it will print the viewcontrollers name from root to onwards.And hence you will know that from which viewController you are coming from.

Comment: No matter if I'm going to or coming bak from another view controller, always print same number of viewControllers. (In my case 2 viewControllers)